# Changed casing of file name and getting casing error, how do I fix?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm building react-redux project.

I created component called `manageCoursePage.js`, and after writing the code and hooking it up to the rest of the app, I decided to rename it as `ManageMyCourse.js` and renamed all my imports as as required. I'm now getting the error

> Casing of ./courses/manageCoursePage does not match the underlying filesystem

React still doesn't seem to recognize the change in filename, so how do I fix this? I tried deleting the component and re-writing it from scratch, which didn't work.

**ManageCoursePage.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as courseActions from "../../redux/actions/courseActions";
import * as authorActions from "../../redux/actions/authorActions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";


class ManageCoursePage extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { courses, authors, loadAuthors, loadCourses } = this.props;

    if (courses.length === 0) {
     loadCourses().catch(error => {
        alert("Loading courses failed" + error);
      });
    }

    if (authors.length === 0) {
      loadAuthors().catch(error => {
        alert("Loading authors failed" + error);
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h2>Manage Course</h2>
      </>
    );
  }
}

ManageCoursePage.propTypes = {
  authors: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  courses: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  loadCourses: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  loadAuthors: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        courses: state.courses,
        authors: state.authors
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps =  {
        loadCourses: courseActions.loadCourses,
        loadAuthors: authorActions.loadAuthors
  }



export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ManageCoursePage);
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './home/HomePage'
import AboutPage from './about/AboutPage'
import Header from './common/Header';
import PageNotFound from './PageNotFound';
import CoursesPage from './courses/CoursesPage';
import ManageCoursePage from './courses/manageCoursePage';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className='container-fluid'>
    <Header/>
        <Routes>
            <Route  exact path="/" element={<HomePage/>}></Route>
            <Route  path="/about" element={<AboutPage/>}></Route>
            <Route  path="/courses" element={<CoursesPage/>}></Route>
            <Route  path="/course/:slug" element={<ManageCoursePage/>}></Route>
            <Route  path="/course/" element={<ManageCoursePage/>}></Route>
            <Route element={<PageNotFound />}></Route>
        </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App
```

Comment: Can you show how you import and export it?

Comment: Oops, I just saw the issue - I had imported the ManageMyCourse component as ./course/manageMyCourse'